# Can we derive the equation of motion of superconductor in this video?

Tags: condensed-matter, superconductivity

Recently, I tried to understand the effect of [Quantum levitation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ws6AAhTw7RA). I read that there is some well-known fact: Relative distance between superconductor and magnet must be preserved, because of flux pinning mostly occurred in type II superconductor. My rough understanding about this is, quantisation of (penetrated) magnetic flux inside the superconductor, and continuity of magnetic flux depending on the distance from the magnet, induces the fixation of relative distance (It couldn't move continuously after fixation because there is no no-jump-but-continuous motion).

I could understand the second part of the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ws6AAhTw7RA). I guess it's because of the circular symmetry of magnetic field. There is nothing hard to understand the story. However, what about the first part?

If we rotate the magnet, then what makes the superconductor follow it? Obviously, it's due to the preservation of relative distance in layman's terms. However, could we more elaborate on it? For instance, in the context of classical electrodynamics, someone could try to explain this by the induced electric fields and currents from time-varying magnetic fields. However, it may not be an answer because of the quantum nature of a superconductor.

The quantised flux varies by the time dependent magnetic field, but could we describe such a variation in terms of the motion of the magnet?, and so, could we derive and describe the equation of motion of a superconductor?